# Error while using google texttospeech : Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available

Tags: java, netty, grpc, google-text-to-speech

Getting the following exception while using GGoogle Text to Speech API,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available
    at i.g.n.s.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:233)
    at i.g.n.s.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:144)
    at i.g.n.s.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:93)
    at i.g.n.s.i.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:397)
    at i.g.i.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:513)
    at c.g.a.g.g.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:304)
    at c.g.a.g.g.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1500(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:71)
    at c.g.a.g.g.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:202)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
    at c.g.a.g.g.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:209)
    at c.g.a.g.g.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:192)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:155)
    at c.g.c.t.v1.stub.GrpcTextToSpeechStub.create(GrpcTextToSpeechStub.java:74)
    at c.g.c.t.v1.stub.TextToSpeechStubSettings.createStub(TextToSpeechStubSettings.java:100)
    at c.g.c.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient.<init>(TextToSpeechClient.java:128)
    at c.g.c.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient.create(TextToSpeechClient.java:109)
    at c.g.c.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient.create(TextToSpeechClient.java:101)
    at com.vxml.util.GoogleTTSUtil.getSpeech(GoogleTTSUtil.scala:11)
    at com.vxml.util.GoogleTTSUtil.getSpeech$(GoogleTTSUtil.scala:10)
    at com.VxmlActivitiesMain$.getSpeech(VxmlActivitiesMain.scala:22)
    at com.vxml.rest.TTSRoute.$anonfun$ttsRoute$2(TTSRoute.scala:35)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive$.$anonfun$addByNameNullaryApply$2(...
```

Used the following sbt dependencies,

```
  val googleTTS              = "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-texttospeech"       % "1.0.2"
  val googleLibraries        = "com.google.cloud" % "libraries-bom"                   % "4.4.1"
  val googleGrpc             = "com.google.api"   % "gax-grpc"                        % "1.56.0"
  val nettyShaded            = "io.grpc"          % "grpc-netty-shaded"               % "1.28.1"
  val nettyTcnativeBoringSsl = "io.netty"         % "netty-tcnative-boringssl-static" % "2.0.20.Final"
```

Docker Base Image used : openjdk:8u212-jdk-alpine

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using base image as alpine, which actually doesn't supports gRPC,
you need to add the gcompact apk in your application.
So, what you can do is :
Using docker :

> RUN apk add gcompat
>
> ENV LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libgcompat.so.0

Answer (score 0):

This link https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#netty says:

> io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded includes the proper version of Netty and netty-tcnative-boringssl-static in a way that won't conflict with other Netty usages.

Can you try removing your own `nettyTcnativeBoringSsl` dependency and see if that solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before the IllegalStateException, [gRPC will dump log messages with additional info](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/461d30adfb38fb552017edeeb85ab90882947920/netty/src/main/java/io/grpc/netty/GrpcSslContexts.java#L226-L232). So the best thing to do would be to look at those messages and determine more of what is happening.

However, since you are running on Alpine, I expect the problem is `Error loading shared library libcrypt.so.1: No such file or directory`. gRPC [mentions in its security documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#netty) that Alpine lacks some compatibility with glibc by default, and compatibility can be restored by installing a package: `apk update && apk add libc6-compat`. This problem is caused by the differences between glibc that is generally used on Linux and musl as used on Alpine.